# How to display NULL when criteria not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this table

```
Column1  Column2
1        value1
2        value2
3        value3
4        value4
```

Using this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2='value2'
```

Only displays this:

```
Column1  Column2
2        value2
```

I want to display this:

```
Column1  Column2
1
2        value2
3
4
```

How?

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this unless you define a @Column2 value parameter...what database system are you using?

Comment: @ltn how does a variable help? And the OP is using SQL Server 2005 (see the tags).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your `WHERE` clause is saying "show me the rows where `column2 = value2`" - so, as written, it can't possibly include any rows where `column2` has any other value, because they've been filtered out.

Here's one way to accomplish what you're looking for, using a `CASE` expression (and no `WHERE` clause):

```
SELECT column1, column2 = CASE 
  WHEN column2 = 'value2' THEN 'value2'
  ELSE NULL
END
FROM dbo.table;
```